# Как сделать стартовое активити фрагмент?

Tags: java, drawerlayout

При открытии приложения,он показывает пустое окно , чтобы перейти в Фрагмент 1 или Фрагмент 2 нужно свайпнуть DrawerLayout.Собственно вопрос: Как можно сделать ,чтобы приложение сразу открывало Фрагмент 1?

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">


<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.olega.chosen.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />
```

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">
```

Вот код DrawerLayout ,если поможет.

Comment: Добавьте фрагмент в разметку или программно в onCreate или программно нажмите на пункт меню в дровере

Comment: Первый способ плох, берите второй. Там надо через менеджер фрагментов начать транзакцию добавить фрагмент и закоммитить её. Код с телефона набирать не удобно, но там всего одна строка

Comment: Удалил лишнее) Не забудьте принять ответ)

Comment: Я не забыл,но мне пишет,что нужно иметь более высокий уровень.Репутация должна быть больше 15

Comment: Вы не можете голосовать, но принимать можете. Нажмите на галочку слева от тела ответа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно добавить фрагмент вручную при создании активити в методе onCeate так:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.cont‌​ainer, new MyFragment()).commit();
```